# How to have a 'model' index and then also a 'model' index for each user(models_path & user_models_path)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes, resources

I have a Tool model and I want to be able to have both a regular tools index (tools_path) that lists all the tools in the database for all users & also an users tool index(users_tools_path) that lists all the tools for a particular user.

I am not sure what the rails way of implementing this is. I am using devise and my instinct was to do the following in my routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users

  root 'tools#index'

  resources :users do
    resources :tools
  end

  resources :tools
end
```

This gets me the following routes:

```
                  Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                              Controller#Action
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)                 devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)                devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)            devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)           devise/passwords#edit
                         PATCH  /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)                devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                  devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)                 devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                    devise/registrations#edit
                         PATCH  /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#update
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                         devise/registrations#destroy
                    root GET    /                                        tools#index
              user_tools GET    /users/:user_id/tools(.:format)          tools#index
                         POST   /users/:user_id/tools(.:format)          tools#create
           new_user_tool GET    /users/:user_id/tools/new(.:format)      tools#new
          edit_user_tool GET    /users/:user_id/tools/:id/edit(.:format) tools#edit
               user_tool GET    /users/:user_id/tools/:id(.:format)      tools#show
                         PATCH  /users/:user_id/tools/:id(.:format)      tools#update
                         PUT    /users/:user_id/tools/:id(.:format)      tools#update
                         DELETE /users/:user_id/tools/:id(.:format)      tools#destroy
                   users GET    /users(.:format)                         users#index
                         POST   /users(.:format)                         users#create
                new_user GET    /users/new(.:format)                     users#new
               edit_user GET    /users/:id/edit(.:format)                users#edit
                    user GET    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#show
                         PATCH  /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
                         PUT    /users/:id(.:format)                     users#update
                         DELETE /users/:id(.:format)                     users#destroy
                   tools GET    /tools(.:format)                         tools#index
                         POST   /tools(.:format)                         tools#create
                new_tool GET    /tools/new(.:format)                     tools#new
               edit_tool GET    /tools/:id/edit(.:format)                tools#edit
                    tool GET    /tools/:id(.:format)                     tools#show
                         PATCH  /tools/:id(.:format)                     tools#update
                         PUT    /tools/:id(.:format)                     tools#update
                         DELETE /tools/:id(.:format)                     tools#destroy
```

This is my tools controller:

```
class ToolsController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_tool, only:[:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
before_action :authenticate_user!, only:[:new, :destroy, :edit], notice: 'you must be logged in to proceed'

    def index
        @tools = Tool.all
    end

    def show
    end

    def new
        @user = current_user
        @tool = @user.tools.build
    end

    def create
        @tool = Tool.new(tool_params)
        @tool.save
        redirect_to @tool
    end

    def edit
    end

    def update
        @tool.update(tool_params)
        redirect_to @tool
    end

    def destroy
        @tool.destroy
        redirect_to tools_path
    end

    private

    def set_tool
        @tool = Tool.find(params[:id])
    end

    def tool_params
        params.require(:tool).permit(:name, :description)
    end

end
```

These are my models:

```
class Tool < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tools
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

Unfortunately at this point when I navigate to `users/id/tools` all the tools in the database are listed instead of only the tools for that particular user. Also when I look at the active record instances of each tool in my database the `user_id` column is `nil`

However I am stuck here. Obviously the code will be different for each index so I can't use the same index action for both situations or the same index.html.erb view page either.

I am wondering wheat the next step would be?

Here are a few things I am thinking I could do:

1) create a new action in my tools controller something like user_index and include the user & tool logic to fetch the tools associated to a particular user. I would also have to create a new `user_index.html.erb` view with the view code. Then I would delete the nested resource and add a route like: `match 'users/:id/tools' => 'tools#user_index', :via => get`

2) I can delete the stand alone `resources :tools` route and the add a `get :user_index, :on => :collection` in my nested tool resource. Then add a user_index action to my controller like in solution #1. The only problem here is that then all my routes would have the `user/:id` prefix which I do not want.

What is the best solution in this case? Also, why are my active record tool instances not saving the id of the user that created them? Is there a way to get them to save the user id without nesting the resources?

What is the rails way for this?

Answer (score 0):

To only show the tools of a particular user, instead of doing:

```
@tools = Tool.all
```

You can make an instance variable that is an array of Tools that are assigned to a particular user. For example:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@tools = Tool.where(user_id: @user.id)
```

This will only collect the tools where the tools user_id matches the user ID of the user loaded into the show view.

Then when you do your loop, it will show the right tools for that user.

Answer (score 0):

With the answer above you can use:

```
@tools = (@user.present?) ? @user.tools : Tool.all
```

To be able to set the user of each tool you have to edit your:``

`params.require(:tool).permit(:name, :description)`

To include user

```
        params.require(:tool).permit(:name, :description, :user)
```